# how to save plist to NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save a `.plist` I have created into my `NSUserDefaults` so that I can save the data that I am putting into it, so if the app is stopped (removed from multitasking bar) I do not loose the values.

I have been pointed to this tutorial [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUserDefaults)

In it is has this sample code.

```
-(void)saveToUserDefaults:(NSString*)myString
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (standardUserDefaults) {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"Prefs"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }
}

-(NSString*)retrieveFromUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *val = nil;

    if (standardUserDefaults) 
        val = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"Prefs"];

    return val;
}
```

What I would like some help with is how dose the above relate to saving `.plists`?

I have a `.plist` controller class which reads the bundle `.plist` creates a new `.plist` in the root document then reads and writes to that... how so I use the above to save it when the app 
exits or turns off?

This is how I am loading and writing to my `.plist`, at the moment using singlettons and it being in its own class.

```
#pragma mark Singleton Methods
+ (id)sharedManager {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedMyManager == nil)
            sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedMyManager;
}
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        // Data.plist code
        // get paths from root direcory
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        // get documents path
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        // get the path to our Data/plist file
        NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"EngineProperties.plist"];

        // check to see if Data.plist exists in documents
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
        {
            // if not in documents, get property list from main bundle
            plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EngineProperties" ofType:@"plist"];
        }

        // read property list into memory as an NSData object
        NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
        NSString *errorDesc = nil;
        NSPropertyListFormat format;
        // convert static property liost into dictionary object
        NSDictionary *tempRoot = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
        if (!tempRoot)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
        }
        // assign values
        self.signature = [tempRoot objectForKey:@"Signature"];
        self.version = [tempRoot objectForKey:@"Version"];
        self.request = [tempRoot objectForKey:@"Request"];
        self.dataVersion = [tempRoot objectForKey:@"Data Version"];

        man = [cacheValue objectForKey:@"Man"];
        mod = [cacheValue objectForKey:@"Mod"];
        sub = [cacheValue objectForKey:@"SubMod"];

        cacheValue = [tempRoot objectForKey:@"Cache Value"];
    }


    - (void) saveData:(NSString *)methodName signature:(NSString *)pSignature Version:(NSNumber *)pVersion request:(NSNumber *)rNumber dataVersion:(NSNumber *)dvReturned cacheValue:(NSNumber *)cValue;
    {
        // get paths from root direcory
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        // get documents path
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        // get the path to our Data/plist file
        NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"EngineProperties.plist"];

        // set the variables to the values in the text fields
        self.signature = pSignature;
        self.version = pVersion;
        self.request = rNumber;
        self.dataVersion = dvReturned;

        //do some if statment stuff here to put the cache in the right place or what have you.
        if (methodName == @"manufacturers")
        {
            self.man = cValue; 
        }
        else if (methodName == @"models")
        {
            self.mod = cValue;
        }
        else if (methodName == @"subMod")
        {
            self.sub = cValue;
        }

        self.cacheValue = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           man, @"Manufacturers",
                           mod, @"Models",
                           sub, @"SubModels", nil];


        NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   signature, @"Signature",
                                   version, @"Version",
                                   request, @"Request",
                                   dataVersion, @"Data Version",
                                   cacheValue, @"Cache Value", nil];



        NSString *error = nil;
        // create NSData from dictionary
        NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

        // check is plistData exists
        if(plistData)
        {
            // write plistData to our Data.plist file
            [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

            NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plistData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            //        NSLog(@"%@", myString);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
            //        [error release];
        }
    }


    @end
```

Comment: You should use either one. I suggest using `NSUserDefaults`. Much cleaner codes.

Comment: right, so you cannot actually save a plist into nsuserdefaults ?

Comment: No you can't. Think of NSUserDefaults as an invisible .plist that you can read and write to, without ever being able to actually see the file.

Comment: MADNESS!!! lol I had a reply in another similar question and the guy suggested I could save plists to NSUser defaults.. I think maybe he did not mean to say that like he said.. which sent me off on this wild goose chase.. what worse now is I have done all of the plist stuff and I am not going to need it now.. thank you for your reply. I am going to go research NSUserDefaults now :P

Comment: so my last question, will NSUserdefaults hold onto my values even if I delete the app from the multitask bar? because if i do that currently my plist values are lost.. and this is what I am trying to prevent.

Comment: Yes it will, I have several apps that count on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't write a `.plist` into `NSUserDefaults`, at least not practically. To achieve this you'll have to write specific keys from the `.plist` into `NSUserDefaults` which is basically like saving two copies of all of your data. You can think of `NSUserDefaults` as an invisible `.plist` that you can read and write to, without ever being able to actually see the file. Using `NSUserDefaults`, you will be able to restore saved values even if the app has been killed in multitasking.

However, how you choose between `.plist` and `NSUserDefaults` should be based off of how much data you need to save. Apple recommends only saving small amounts of data to `NSUserDefaults`. If you need to save a lot of information then `.plist` is the way to go. Either that or of course `Core-Data`.

Comment: any chance you could resolve mine and Vignesh differences on plists loosing their values when being removed from the background?

Comment: @MDT Why can't we write a plist in NSUserdefaults, Can't we store NSData in NSUserDefaults?.

Comment: @Vignesh you caught me before an edit, you can do this but it isn't really practical to do so.

Answer (score 0):

.plist is a key-value pair file. Which is essentially a dictionary. 
When you store data in a .plist you are persisting it. You can get it back even your app is killed.

NSUserDefaults does the same. It is more cleaner and faster. So either one approach is enough.

Comment: Thanks for youre reply, I would just like to point out that I have done fairly extensive testing on my plist that i created and yes the values will stay in your plist if you exit your application. However if you delete it from the multitask bar (not sure on correct terminology) then you will loose the value stored in the plist that you copied to your root documents folder for read/write capabilites.

Comment: @C.Johns,  No. I don't think so. It will persist.

Comment: hrmm.. well maybe I am missing something then. But I have looked everywhere and cannot find any way to make the plist values persistent when an app is being removed (stopped running) from the background. would be nice to have someone provide me some code on how to stop this from happening because they I could use it instead of having to start up with NSUserDefaults.

Comment: May i know why am i downvoted?. How is it different from the accepted answer.?.

Comment: So the difference between what you said and MDT, was that you specified that plists are able to hold their value even after the app is killed.. From the experience + testing I have done on trying to hold the values of a plist when its killed from the background makes this answer (for me anyway) slightly incorrect. Hence for my downvote.. and explination I have already given above... If you are able to provide information that I am incorrect I would be more than happy to reverse the vote.. I'm sorry if I upset you but its nothing personal

Comment: @C.Johns We are here to share and learn. I just wanted to know where i went wrong. you will get opportunity to learn from mistakes. Its no personal. Ok. Let me substantiate my answer. When you write a file in disk it will persist. .plist or a database file all are files of different format. NSUserDefauts is nothing but a specialized application wide database that's all. When you write into plist file it will get stored in your sandbox. once it is done. it will persist.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9940/discussion-between-c-johns-and-vignesh)

Comment: well I wrote in the discussion but you have not come across.. ill try and make this shorted. When i first run my app I check for the plist i want to  create.. if its not there I signal an alert.. I only ever get this when the app is first built which means its persistant.. no matter what (unless app is deleted from phone) however when ever i delete the app from multitasking then I loose the values inside the plist...