# NSUserDefaults and NSPropertyListSerialization

Tags: xml, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I'm writing some preferences using NSUserDefaults although I would like to save them in XML format (currently it's saving in binary by default). I've seen [some examples of saving .plists using NSPropertylistSerialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098512/how-to-save-plist-to-nsuserdefaults), however they look overly complicated. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"Button One"];
[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"Button Two"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 1):

.plist that you created with Xcode interface is readable but not writeable. If you want to make changes to the file in the project Bundle primarily in one of the folders within the Documents or Library to copy and then there always have to work on the copy or create the .plist with code.

Creating:

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];

NSArray* fruits= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"apple", @"orange", @"cherry", nil];
NSArray* vegetables= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"cabbage", @"pumpkin", @"leek", nil];

NSDictionary* dictionary= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fruits, @"fruits", vegetables, @"vegetables", nil];

[dictionary writeToFile:plistPath  atomically:YES];
```

Reading and Writing:

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];

NSDictionary* dictionary= [[NSDictionary alloc] plistPath ];

NSMutableArray* fruits= [dictionary objectForKey:@"fruits"];
NSMutableArray* vegetables= [dictionary objectForKey:@"vegetables"];

NSLog(@"First Fruit: %@",[fruits objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"First Vegetable: %@",[vegetables objectAtIndex:0]);

[fruits replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"banana"];

[dictionary writeToFile:plistYolu atomically:YES];
```

Comment: the .plist already exists in ~/library/preferences, but it seems when I use it through NSUserDefaults it writes it as binary instead of XML. I tried to use an NSTask with plutil, but that fails for some reason giving me an error `/usr/bin/plutil ("-convert xml1","userdefaults.plist") unrecognized option: -convert xml1.` When I paste the command into terminal it works fine :/ — So basically what you're saying is I can't write the NSUserDefaults and save as XML? I have to create the a new preferences file and do it like your example? Thanks